# Getting the boolean skeleton of a satisfiable SMT formula in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, sat

Is there a way to extract the boolean/propositional skeleton in Z3 for a formula that is satisfiable?

Thanks,

Hrishi

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want to give to Z3 and what you want to get in return? It sounds like naming subformulas and querying the value of these names would be sufficient.